# How to get table content and put it in a variable as multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to do is to get the table contents and put it in a jquery variable as multidimensional array. Is this possible thing? Can anyone give me an example thanks.

[image]

Comment: I would highly suggest you refrain from multidimensional arrays. Use an array of objects. I.e., each row is an index in an array and the columns are the `key: value` pairs.

Comment: 1) yes 2) what have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that by *"table content"* you mean *"the data"*, you could nest calls to [`jQuery.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/antisanity/k4be3/)):

```
// for each content row, retrieve an array of cell-text values
var data = $.map($("tbody tr"), function (tr) {
    return [$.map(tr.cells, function (td) {
        return $(td).text();
    })];
});
```

output:

```
[
    ["four", "4", "Female"],
    ["one", "1", "Male"],
    ["three", "3", "Female"],
    ["two", "2", "Male"]
]
```

... and in plain javascript ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/antisanity/t39kz/)):

```
var data = [].map.call(document.querySelectorAll("tbody tr"), function (tr) {
    return [].map.call(tr.cells, function(td) {
       return td.textContent; 
    });
});
```

Now, [as others have suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25045008/how-to-get-table-content-and-put-it-in-a-variable-as-multidimensional-array#comment38955348_25045008), you could (and perhaps *should*) consider an array of objects instead ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/antisanity/LB6Wx/)):

```
// get the header names so we can use them for our object property names
var names = [].map.call(document.querySelectorAll("thead th"), function (th) {
    return th.textContent;
});

// for each content row, retrieve an object-representation of the data
var data = [].map.call(document.querySelectorAll("tbody tr"), function (tr) {
    return [].reduce.call(tr.cells, function (p, td, i) {
        p[names[i]] = td.textContent;
        return p;
    }, {});
});
```

output:

```
[{
    "Name": "four",
    "Age": "4",
    "Gender": "Female"
}, {
    "Name": "one",
    "Age": "1",
    "Gender": "Male"
}, {
    "Name": "three",
    "Age": "3",
    "Gender": "Female"
}, {
    "Name": "two",
    "Age": "2",
    "Gender": "Male"
}]
```

<sub>See [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Map) and [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) on MDN.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Vanilla javascript (without jQuery, as you didn't state it in the initial question):

```
var multArray = []; // The multi dimensional array
var tableId = "#mytable"; // Change this according to your html
var rows = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(tableId + " tr"));
var td, x = 0 , y = 0;

rows.forEach(function(row){
  row = [].slice.call(row.querySelectorAll("td"));
  multArray.push(row.map(function(x){return x.innerHTML || "";}))
})
```

Demo:
http://jsbin.com/cireyuka/1/edit

*Note:*
I must say that multi-dimensional arrays aren't the best case for you in most cases.
What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery you can try this:

```
var myTableAsArray = (function(){ 
      var retval =[]; 
      $('#your_table').find('tr').each(function(it,ele){ 
          var cells = $(ele).find('td'); 
          var tmp = { 
                    Name: cells.eq(0).text(), 
                    Age: cells.eq(1).text(), 
                    Gender: cells.eq(2).text() 
          }; 
          retval.push(tmp);  
      });  
      return retval; 
    })();
```

Then you got an array with objects like in pattmorter comment.

Answer (score -1):

Some example code for something that I've written that's similar. Hopefully this should give you an idea!

```
   $('#tableAssortmentList tr').each(function () {
        // if you want specific or all cells
        $(this).find('td.cell.id').each(function () {
            //do your stuff, you can use $(this) to get current cell
            priceArray.push($(this).text().substring(1));
        })

    })
```